# mde/timezone-js - Use with multiple cities ? (currently only few cities like only Kolkata from India)

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, dst

https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

The above returns date of particular timezone using :

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('America/New_York');
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('Asia/Kolkata');
```

To my research, it is accepting very few cities (like only Kolkata from India). How can I make it work with all major cities of all countries?

Answer (score 0):

This is an recurring subject of discussion on the `tz@iana.org` mailing list.  The basic answer is that there is one name in the Olson database for each time zone, and for India it is Asia/Kolkata (and for the USA, the Pacific time zone is identified by America/Los_Angeles, for example).  In general, the name used identifies a continent and the largest city in the time zone at the time when the list was first created (there are other criteria too; they're documented in the Theory file that comes with the Olson database data). These names are for internal use; they are semi-meaningful to humans, but they are not presented in the best possible way (no country, names with underscores replacing blanks, Anglicized names, etc).

The recommended way of dealing with this is to create your own list of city names, probably with country information too, and map each to the appropriate time zone.

Beware that doing this thoroughly is really quite hard.  Some zones are quite small.  One that has been under discussion recently is Europe/Busingen; it is a German 'exclave' that did not always change time at the same time as the surrounding Swiss cantons, rather keeping to Berlin time (or therabouts).  You run into similar issues in parts of the USA; the state of Indiana has numerous places inside which have changed between winter and summer (standard and daylight saving) time differently, some parts being in the Eastern time zone, some in Central, and some parts not changing time zone at all (so the time zone is the same as Eastern in winter and Central in summer).  There's a town (region) in China where the Han (Chinese) population uses China time (Asia/Shanghai, UTC+08:00), but the local population uses a different time zone (UTC+06:00); same place, different time zones for different people.  The area is Xinjiang; the entry is Asia/Urumqi.

---

You can download the data and code from:

- http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzcode2012j.tar.gz
- http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2012j.tar.gz
- ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases/tzcode2012j.tar.gz
- ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/releases/tzdata2012j.tar.gz

I'm not certain whether all historical versions are available from the IANA site.

You need to know the current version number for this notation (2012j — the 10th edition in 2012, released on 2012-11-12).  The general 'latest' version links are:

- http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzcode-latest.tar.gz
- http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz
- ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzcode-latest.tar.gz
- ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tzdata-latest.tar.gz

These names do not change, so they'll always retrieve the latest version.  However, the file names do not tell you what the current version is; you have to look inside to find that out — you win some, you lose some.